# Java Directory Search - Cast Sensitive and Can only search 1 string

Tags: java, filewriter, directorysearcher

```
File fe = new File("C:\\Users\\" + System.getProperty("user.name") + "\\desktop" + "\\SearchResults.txt");
    String customLoca = "C:\\Users\\" + System.getProperty("user.name") + "\\AppData" + "\\roaming" + "\\.minecraft" + "\\mods" + "\\1.7.10";

    FileWriter fw = null;
    try {
        fw = new FileWriter(fe);
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    File dir = new File(customLoca);
    for (File f : dir.listFiles()) {
        if (f.getName().contains("Toggle")){ 
            try {
                fw.write("Found: "   + f.getName());
                fw.write("\r\n===");
                fw.write("\r\n"); 

            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }
    try {
        fw.close();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

}
}
```

Basically the code above creates a text document with the results in. This works however I have to make it case-exact with the file I want it to find. For example if I replaced "Toggle" with "toggle" nothing would appear. Is there a way I can make this Case-Insensitive? Also, is there a way I can add an else argument. So if nothing was found it would print "Nothing Found" in the text document. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with `!string.equalsIgnoreCase()` in your check - try to apply something like this:

```
if (!toggle.equalsIgnoreCase(file.getName()))
```

**EDIT:**

You can also try to refactor this piece of code:

```
        StringBuilder paragraph = new StringBuilder();
        paragraph.append("I am at office.")
                .append("I work at oFFicE.")
                .append("My OFFICE");
        String searchWord = "office";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(searchWord, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(paragraph);
        int count = 0;
        while (matcher.find())
            count++;
        System.out.println(count);
```

Comment: I would surely have to create !toggle to a variable? I basically want it to search the directory for a file with the file name containing "toggle". I would also like to add multiple arguments. So it searches for file names "toggle" + "CPS" + "Direction"

Answer (score 0):

Can't use equalsIgnoreCase() because it requires matching the whole name.
recommendations:

- use a Regex to match your name
- use try with resources
- try can span the whole method, multiple tries is slower
- use StringBuilder to cat string (not as critical as it used to be)
- Java doesn't require \r - \n will write an OS appropriate newline
- never catch Exception, this is an overgeneralization
- You can use a String "reset" instead of else, though else works as well.

  ```
   File fe = new File("C:\\Users\\" + System.getProperty("user.name") + "\\desktop" +
                             "\\SearchResults.txt");
   String customLoca =
          "C:\\Users\\" + System.getProperty("user.name") + "\\AppData" + "\\roaming" +
                  "\\.minecraft" + "\\mods" + "\\1.7.10";

  try (FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(fe))
  {
     File dir = new File(customLoca);
       for (File f : dir.listFiles())
       {
         String contents = "Nothing Found";
         if (f.getName().matches("(?i).*toggle.*")));
         {
             contents = new StringBuilder("Found: ")
                         .append(f.getName())
                         .append("\n===\n").toString();
         }
         fw.write(contents);
      }
  } 
  catch (IOException ioe)
  {
      ioe.printStackTrace();
  }
  ```

Comment: Hello thank you for this however this code is doing the same thing. It lists all the files in the directory? I'll post a screenshot: https://gyazo.com/b47ccba9b76bb39e2f6d0bc65e54fbf7

Comment: f.getName().matches("(?i)Toggle")
Should only match names like: TOGGle, ToggLe and toggle. If it doesn't, I made a mistake in creating the RegEx. Modify it so it does match those cases. This is great Unit Test to write.

Comment: Regex edited and WFM. Try it again.
Note this matches Strings that contain "toggle" in any case. It will match "dToGgleERTY" but not "dToGleERTY"